# How to build a JMeter request using multiple lines from a CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I need to build a batch request which pulls multiple rows from a CSV file. Unfortunately each request only pull a single row from CSV file. So a request like
`[ ${order}, ${order} ]` will produce request with same order ids like `[100, 100]`.

Some people suggested JSR223 pre-processor, but the solution needs to load the CSV file for each request which seems very inefficient. Does anyone have other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I extended the cvs plugin to pull a batch of data into variables, then use JSR223 to build the batch request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can take a look at [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) where you have full control where on when to proceed to the next line
2. You can take a look at [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) which reads next line from the file each time it's being called
3. The approach with [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) is fine, if you want to avoid reading the whole file each time by each thread you can do it once somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) and either put the whole file into JMeter Properties or copy individual lines there.

   ```
   List<String> lines = new File('test.csv').readLines()
   props.put('lines', lines)

   //or

    1.upto(lines.size(), {
        props.put("line_$it", lines.get(it - 1))
    })
   ```